# Grouping and Sorting a Collection with Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, grouping

I have a list of people which I would like to group based on their age (group1 has age < 20, group2 has age >=20) and sort each group based on name and age using Java 8:
List of people:

Group 1:

```
Ane 12
Col 14
```

Group 2:

```
James 24
thomas 34
Xavier 55
```

I would like to use Java 8 to do something like this:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(...
```

Comment: Do you want the groups sorted by name first or age first?

Comment: @akaliza is the question about splitting the list into two groups, or grouping them by multiple age ranges? If it's about grouping by age range, you could update your question for clarity (and to let me fix my answer proposal :))

Answer (score 7):

You can get to what you want by:

- Sorting your whole collection of people by age (and then name).
- Partitioning it.

Note that the order of each partition will be maintained:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.partitioningBy;

people.stream()
  .sorted(
     comparing(Person::getAge)
       .thenComparing(Person::getName))
  .collect(partitioningBy(p -> p.getAge() >= 20))
```

<sub>Thanks to Christoffer for his improvement proposal: Scandinavian Java must be as slick as a set of IKEA assembly instructions :)</sub>

Comment: You should be using `Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge)`.

Comment: Thanks, it's cleaner that way :)

Comment: Also, to make it even cleaner, `import static java.util.Collectors.partitioningBy` and `import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;`

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the [`partitioningBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-) collector instead.  It will allow you to specify a predicate and return a map keyed by a boolean:

```
Map<Boolean, List<?>> partitioned = list.stream().sorted(...).collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(...));
```

Comment: what if I want people between age 20 and 50? can I chain partitioningBy?

Comment: Not really.  In that case you'll need to write a function which returns a different value for each group, and then do a `groupingBy` with that function.

Comment: I understand, we have a predicate, therefore I can do this p -> p.getAge() >= 20 &&  p.getAge() <50

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted three groups: a <20, a 20-50, and a >50.  If you want one group of 20-50 and the other of everyone else, that will work.

Comment: what if I want 3 groups ? what should I do ? I am new to Java8

Comment: ok, if I need this a <20, a 20-50, and a >50, I need to have 3 partitioned map, is that correct ?

Comment: Basically, yes.